# from invalid argument: 'value' must be a single Unicode code point error using ActionChains class of Selenium through Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, action

```
File "C:/Users/User/Test.py", line 58, in <module> 
.send_keys(DTD) \

selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument
from invalid argument: 'value' must be a single Unicode code point
```

This is the error I encountered when I send_keys to Date filed on Chrome browser.

The followings are my data and part of code.

1. Data

[image]

2. Part of code

```
    wb = pandas.read_excel(excel.xlsx)
    Journal = wb.values.tolist()

    for JV in Journal:
        DTD = str(JV[0])         #Date
        Actions(driver) \        #Make entry to the filed on google chrome browser
            .send_keys(DTD) \
            .perform()
```

Comment: It seems like error on ActionChain.

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument
from invalid argument: 'value' must be a single Unicode code point
```

...implies that there was a compatibility issue while converting a **non** `w3c` command to `w3c` standard command.

As per the discussion in [ActionChains perform returns exception 'value' must be a single unicode point](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/12255) this issue was observed with  [appium](/questions/tagged/appium) Version 1.11.1 when used along with *ChromeDriver v2.45* setting the standards mode with:

```
goog:chromeOptions.w3c:true
```

Excert from [release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/75.0.3770.8/notes.txt):

> Resolved issue 2536: Make standards mode (goog:chromeOptions.w3c:true) the default [Pri-2]

---

### Solution

An immediate solution would be to:

- Update *ChromeDriver* to  current [ChromeDriver v78.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=78.0.3904.70/) level.
- Update *Chrome* to  current *Chrome Version 78.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v78.0.3904.105 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=78.0.3904.105/))

---

### tl; dr

A couple of relevant discussions are as follows:

- [perform() action chain - Getting exception](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/12161)
- [ActionsChains key_action.pause causes "exception 'value' must be a single unicode point" in Appium Webview or Chromium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/7000)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. 
I updated following things but it still same. 
- chromedriver to v78.0 level //
- google chrome browser //
- all related python packages //
What I feel strange is it worked..... but all of sudden it doesn't. 
It will be appreciated if you share any additional idea on this issue. 
Thank you again for your big help

Comment: @GeeAhn One last thing would be to use [ChromeDriver 79.0.3945.36](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=79.0.3945.36/)